# Test Excluded Instrument in R PLM package

Tags: r, econometrics, instrumental-variables, plm

I have to run a regression to estimate the impact of an endogenous variable.

There are many packages for this in R (e.g., AER, sem, etc). Since I have an unbalanced panel, in order to obtain a robust estimation of standard errors, I need to use the plm package.

Following a example with a balanced panel of 200 observations along 5 years.

```
set.seed(123)
library(plm)
# independent variable
y <- rnorm(1:1000)
# endogenous variable
x <- runif(1000, 2, 20)
# other regressor
z <- rnorm(1:1000)
# exogenous variable: i.e., instrument
inst <- runif(1000, 1, 10)
# individual fixed effects
id <- rep(1:200,5)
# time fixed effects
year <- Reduce("c",lapply(1:5,function(x) rep(x,200)))
# create database for plm package
lmdb <- cbind(y,x,z,inst,id,year)
p.lmdb <- plm.data(data.frame(lmdb), c("id", "year"))
# IV regression
my_iv_reg <- plm(y~x+z|.-x+inst,data=p.lmdb, model = "within", effect = "twoways", index = c("id","year"))
```

Using the AER package, in order to obtain the F test for the excluded instrument, I would run

```
library(AER)
my_iv_reg_AER <- ivreg(y~x+z+as.factor(id)+as.factor(year)|.-x+inst,data=as.data.frame(lmdb))
summary(my_iv_reg_AER, vcov = sandwich, df = Inf, diagnostics = TRUE)
```

I was wondering if I can run a similar test to detect a weak instrument using the plm package.

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about the correct estimation of standard errors, and you don't have any other particular reason to use the plm package, you can use the `lfe` package. Still, you can use the data created with the plm package

```
library(lfe)
form_iv <- formula(y~z | id + year | x ~ inst)
my_iv_reg <- felm(form_iv, data = p.lmdb)
wald_iv <- waldtest(my_iv_reg$stage1, ~deg_alu, lhs=my_iv_reg$stage1$lhs)
```

The value of the F-test is the fifth value of the waldtest function, i.e.

```
wald_iv[5]
```

While the significance of the F-test is the fourth value of the waldtest function, i.e.,

```
wald_iv[4]
```

Note that if you have more than one instrument, e.g. inst_1 and inst_2, and you need to estimate their joint significance, you can run:

```
form_iv <- formula(y~z | id + year | x ~ inst_1 + inst_2)
my_iv_reg <- felm(form_iv, data = p.lmdb)
wald_iv <- t(sapply(my_iv_reg$stage1$lhs, function(lh){ 
                    waldtest(my_iv_reg$stage1, ~inst_1|inst_2, lhs=lh)} ))
```

Comment: I've been trying to replicate the first stage F stat produced by Stata's `reghdfe` command using `lfe` in R for a linear regression with a single cluster, but always ended up with a much lower F stat in R (e.g. R: 34, Stata: 56). I tried both `lfe::waldtest` and this script from r-bloggers: https://www.r-bloggers.com/detecting-weak-instruments-in-r/, they both ended up producing the same number, which is lower than Stata's first stage F stat. The point estimates are identical. Any idea what might have caused the first stage F-stat discrepancy?